# How we can send real time notification from backend in laravel to frontend in angular

Tags: angular, laravel

How we can send real time notification from backend in laravel to frontend in angular. We are following this link 
https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/push-notifications-with-laravel-and-webpush-446884265aaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `laravel-websockets` for backed:

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets

And **Laravel Echo** for js:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

I can help with the configuration if you decide to use them.